# Error: No Lightning Web Component quick actions are available for your org

Tags: lightning-web-components, quickaction

Trying to add a record action for a custom object using a Lightning Web Component, but I am getting this error:

[image]

This is my component meta.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>false</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to mark your component as exposed so you can see it in your org, so your xml file would look like this. Right now your isExposed tag is set to false, so until you set that to true it won't show up

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>52.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Didn't work for me.  The only difference is my component uses version 54 of the API.

Comment: adding <target>lightning__RecordPage</target> is sufficient, no need for anything else

Answer (score 2):

I had to add some tag inside of my template, like:

```
<template> 
     <p>test</p> 
</template>
```

alongside having all the other suggested changes to the target and targetconfigs.
After I added that, it started showing up.